# Объявление переменной в C#

Tags: c#

Необходимо задать переменную, которую можно было бы использовать в любом методе класса. Где нужно сделать объявление?

т.е. я создала `public class`
в нем у меня есть несколько подпрограмм `public static void`. нужно задать переменную,которую я могу использовать в каждой подпрограмме. если просто задаю в первой подпрограмме эту переменную как `public double a;` весь остальной код сразу окрашивается в красный.
Причем мне необходимо в одной из подпрограмме рассчитать значение этой переменной,а в следующих подпрограммах,чтобы уже подставлялось рассчитанное значение.

Comment: в плане где? там где и всегда

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Есть нюансы: например, если переменную надо использовать в статическом методе, то она тоже должна быть статической, но на место объявления переменной это не влияет.

Comment: [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Попробуй создать приватную переменную класса. Так как методы(подпрограммы в вашем понимании, хотя в шарп нет такого понятия в отношении класса) статические переменная также должна быть статической.

```
public static class Foo
{

private static int a = 0;

public static void Inc()
{
    a++;
...
}

public static void Dec()
{
    a--;
...
}

}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?